# Admin user is unable to login

Tags: 7, users

I've just changed the view of login form to Drupal default view. Now I am not able to log in as administrator.

I have tried to change the password using `php .\scripts\password-hash.sh newpwd`.  I got an hashed password, I used to update the password stored in the database with a SQL query, but still I am not able to log in. I have also cleared entries from flood table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Drush?

Comment: @Gulok  no Im not having drush as Im working in windows

Comment: Hmnn you can still install Drush in Windows. Gaining access to an account is piece of cake using Drush.

Comment: Actually what you did were correct. I am not sure why you are still unable to access you account. May I know the exact sql query you did?

Comment: UPDATE users SET pass= 'hashedpassword' where uid = 1

Comment: You can comment out all hook_form_alter code in custom modules, then try to login again.

Comment: @Jimmy Ko I haven't use any hook_form_alter in my custom modules

Comment: Then I would recommend `drush` as @Gulok mentioned. It is possible to install one in Windows.

Comment: @Jimmy Ko could you plx guide me for installation of drush in windows . I have searched it many times but still unable to install it

Comment: @UmairYousaf Did you check this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/594744)? What I did before is following this.

Comment: For the future, edit the closed question to make it on-topic, instead of asking another question.

Comment: What do you mean by _I've just changed the view of login form to Drupal default view_?

Comment: @ kiamlaluno if have resolved this issue. Thanks for taking it in account

Answer (score 1):

- Please check if you are using the correct username (you can see that
  in the database).
- Try to use the "Forgotten password" function to reset your password
- Check the last entries of the watchdog table to see if you can get
  more information from there
- Check your server logs to see if you get any error there (under Linux
  this would normally be somewhere under /var/logs).
- Install drush and use that to very easily log in
  (https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/user/user-login/)

Answer (score 0):

if drush is installed,

> use **drush uli** or **drush uli uid** (you have to copy like this
>   http://YOURSITE/user/reset/1/1470908634/UyfrRRADUusWPoS2wbHZklaBzi1s111JsOeDsJA7Zus
>   ) this is an example for admin(root)

and set password in admin page.